# soapui 5.x script assertion not implemented for json error

Tags: json, groovy, soapui, assertion

since upgrading to the latest soapUI pro version (5.1.2) I have noticed that I cannot right click on a node in the outline response mode and use the 'Add Assertion -> for Existence with Script' feature. This feature works in the older versions of soapUI. I need this because I need to get the correct namespace setting for the node I want to assert.
Does anyone know if this is a limitation of the newer version or soapUI ? or do I need to tweak the configuration somewhere?

Comment: When is the last time it worked, for your specific case? If you have the -Pro version, then you also have access to support - submit it as a bug, and see what they say.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, the soapUI support forum seems to have been updated recently, i'm awaiting approval in order to be added to the pro support area, i'll let you know what they reply with

Comment: No approval needed here: http://www.soapui.org/support/support-overview.html